# HTML file call to calculation function

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time delving into an HTML editor with goal of learning it. I opened the website [option-price.com](http://www.option-price.com/index.php) and right clicked in chrome to get the [source](http://view-source:http://www.option-price.com/index.php).

I am not able to figure where the real calculation happens when I hit the button `Calculate`.

Comment: Why are there downvotes ?

Comment: Looks for tutorials on Google if you really want to learn web development. And you will not be able to see how it works because calculations are made server-side here (= in PHP).

Comment: If you look at the source Tab you'll see the different javascript files, where I assume the logic happen on some sort of `onSubmit` event. But the source code is minified, it is gonna be very difficult to find anything. Oh and as other comment suggest most likely the calculation would be done in the back-end

Comment: Should I close this question and delete it?

Comment: Stack Overflow questions about code should include the code they are asking about. When that site goes down, or changes its code, this question and its answers will make little sense.

Comment: You are getting downvotes because the audience expects a certain level of proficiency before asking a question.They expect a question to be specific and answerable. Your question is in effect. “I don’t know how any of this works, can someone please explain it all to me?”  I would recommend searching  “How web apps work”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly such content is embedded.like most of the web pages don't allow you to see the source code. 
But
Firebug is a discontinued free and open-source web browser extension for Mozilla Firefox that facilitated the live debugging, editing, and monitoring of any website's CSS, HTML, DOM, XHR, and JavaScript.

Comment: Firebug is discontinued because all browsers have built in dev tools now

Answer (score 1):

Such calculations would not typically be on the front-end - they would likely be happening on whatever back-end they are using (ex. PHP, Django, etc.) by making a server call, which is definitely not displayed in the source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the console (`option + cmd + J` on Mac and Chromium), and not the source.
Then you might want to look at the `Sources` tab, and try and find the Javascript (file or from the HTML (here `index.php`) responsible for what you want to debug. However it seems for this very site that the Calculate does a server call to do the calculation.